# Jupyter Notebook: Sparks's printt() function doesn't print

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, jupyter-notebook

I'm following this tutorial: [Getting Started with Spark Streaming with Python and Kafka](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/fb033086b285655ffe7f9ff0582dedbf)

I'm copypasting the code to my Jupiter Notebook (Python 3).

At cmd 7 they go:

```
parsed.count().map(lambda x:'Tweets in this batch: %s' % x).pprint()
```

but it doesn't print anything.

I don't know if there is actually some data in the dataset, but count() should return some number even if it's zero, shouldn't it?

I'm completely new to Jupyter Notebook.

The entire code:

```
#1
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 pyspark-shell'

#2
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

#3
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_01")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

#4
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)

#5
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'cdh57-01-node-01.moffatt.me:2181', 'spark-streaming', {'twitter':1})

#6
parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))

#7
parsed.count().map(lambda x:'Tweets in this batch: %s' % x).pprint()
```

I've tried:

```
import sys
from importlib import reload
reload(sys)
```

But it didn't help. I manage to print other stuff out, for example if I just type "Hello world" in a cell.

Comment: `ssc.start()`  `ssc.awaitTermination()` after your code.

Comment: @Vishal correct. You can write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this after your code:

```
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```